# How can I access a Range inside a filtered list to retrieve the values? VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to access the values in C(Number):D(Number) inside the filtered list, however I seem to be doing something wrong because the MsgBox never shows up.

```
'Filter only numeric values 
With MaterialListSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("B1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="0*"
    End With

Set rangeInventory = InventorySheet.Range("N1:N" & Rows.Count)
' I had Set rangeMaterialList = MaterialListSheet.Range("B1:B" & Rows.Count) in the beginning but I realized If I need C and D i'm only selecting B 

    Set rangeMaterialList = MaterialListSheet.Range("B1:F" & Rows.Count)

    For Each CellML In rangeMaterialList.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        BomCodesToSplit = CellML.Range("C" & Rows.Row & ":D" & Rows.Row).Values
        MsgBox BomCodesToSplit
        For Each CellI In rangeInventory.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        Next CellI

Next CellML
```

Tried this but no luck:

```
BomCodesToSplit = MaterialListSheet.Range("C" & Rows.Row & ":D" & Rows.Row).Values
```

I'd like to select

```
C1:D1
C2:D2
C3:D3
.
.
.
```

Meaning something like this so it selects it depending on the loop index

```
Cn:Dn
```

In some other programming languages I would use the index of the loop but since I'm new to VBA I have no idea how to do this.

How to achieve this?

Comment: `CellML.Row & CellML.Column`?

Comment: Please understand I'm new to VBA and I'm not clear on these concepts. How do I select C's and D's for each iteration?

Comment: I think @mehow has the beginnings of the solution.  I seem to recall that with filtered ranges, you may also need to iterate over the range's `.Areas` and then iterate the rows/cells within each area.

Comment: `CellML.Range("C" & Rows.Row & ":D" & Rows.Row).Values` --> `CellML.Range("C" & CellML.Row & ":D" & CellML.Row).Values`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are doing but you can use the iterating variable property.

In `for each` loops iterating over some range it's best to use the Range type variable to get the intellisense

example

```
Dim cell as Range
for each cell in Range("A1:A10")
    debug.? cell.Value, cell.Address, cell.Row, cell.Column
next
```

Note: as you type the `cell.` you get an intellisense which only lists the properties that are currently available to the object you are working with.

Comment: I read this, but I modified it to loop over just the results of the filter, otherwise there would be no point in applying it. I'll try this

Comment: This helped me to figure out to do it with MaterialListSheet.Range("C" & CellML.Row & ":C" & CellML.Row).Value. And I had to change  Set rangeMaterialList = MaterialListSheet.Range("B1:F" & Rows.Count) to  Set rangeMaterialList = MaterialListSheet.Range("B1:B" & Rows.Count) because it was taking all rows and turns out, it works without the all the cells. Thank you very much